# default path issue with static files with Suave, in F#

Tags: f#, suave

I am not understanding the doc when it comes to serving static files.

I have a site where the backend is deployed to /app in a docker container and the front end part is deployed to /app/frontend

The main file for the front end is at: /app/frontend/index.html

In the config I have this:

```
homeFolder = Some "/app/frontend"
```

and then:

```
GET >=> choose
    [
        path "/healthcheck" >=> Successful.OK "ok"
        pathScan "/checkqr/%s" checkQRCode
        path "/" >=> Files.file "index.html"
        Files.browseHome
    ]
```

when I go to *domain.com* I get a 404 but when I go to *domain.com/index.html* I get the index.

what did I miss with the syntax? I would like to serve the index.html file when going to *domain.com*

---

Tests done in the meantime:

```
path "/" >=> Files.browse "index.html"
path "/" >=> Files.file "index.html"
path "/" >=> Files.browseFile "/app/frontend" "index.html"
path "/" >=> Files.browseFile "frontend" "index.html"
path "/" >=> Files.sendFile "index.html" true
path "/" >=> Files.file (Files.resolvePath "/app/frontend" "index.html")
path "/" >=> Files.browseFileHome "index.html"
path "/" >=> Files.file "/app/frontend/index.html"
```

none of them work.
I confirmed, the file is at /app/frontend/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Files.file` doesn't look in the home folder, but `Files.browseFileHome` does:

```
path "/" >=> Files.browseFileHome "index.html"
```

I agree that the documentation is very fuzzy on this.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get a 404

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what to say. It works fine for me. You could also try resolving the path manually, like this: `path "/" >=> Files.file (Files.resolvePath home "index.html")`, where `home` is a string containing the home folder's path.

Comment: I put an edit with all the tests I have done. Maybe the way I define the home folder is wrong but it's just an absolute path: /app/frontend

Comment: sorry, this was my fault with new code not running and I wasted a day testing the old one :/ docker can be fun... your answer is good!